# LWJGL—How to Animate and Render Characters Using a Sprite Sheet

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm making an RPG similar to Super Nintendo RPGs in the early '90s. I'm handling movement much like Squaresoft's *Final Fantasy IV*. [image: FFIV Gameplay]

Notice that the player never actually **changes his x and y positions on screen**. What I'm asking, to be precise, is how could I, in LWJGL through user input (say, the arrow keys), take the **sprite sheet I have of my character's movement animations** and render them in a [partially] fluid animation like above?

I've been perusing the internet for hours, and I've not found a surefire way to do this. I don't have any code as of yet; I'm more or less looking for a guideline or some pointers in the right direction concerning how I might tackle this.

And, to note, this'll be a rather large game, so I want to focus partially on speed and efficiency—that meaning that I don't want to dive into Slick2D and libGDX unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I don't. I've been searching the internet for hours, and I'm hardly sure where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that enumerating over a series of `BufferedImage[]` is your best bet for a homemade solution. Someone made a simple example [over here.](http://www.java-gaming.org/topics/lwjgl-best-way-to-handle-2d-sprite-animations/33151/msg/318685/view.html#msg318685) Pull the images from your spritesheet to create the array, then just swap between the sprites as desired. Possibly building an `AnimationManager` to move between `Animations` could help.